# Appgrid not responding on application pages

Tags: 16.04

After becoming frustrated with the new Ubuntu Software, I installed Appgrid. It works fine until I try to peruse the individual applications, where it stops responding. This is a fresh install of 16.04

Comment: Have you tried solving the issues you have with Ubuntu Software Center?
Is this relevant to you https://bugs.launchpad.net/appgrid/+bug/1543752 ?? If yes please login there and mark affect me too.